# Calculator in C++ with different types and operations to choose

Tags: c++, types, numbers, switch-statement

I'm about to create simple calculator in C++. It should allow user to chose type and operations on two typed numbers. So at first, user have to choose number type from list(which shows different types like int, double, short etc.). After that it should allow you to write two numbers of type that you selected before. Then at the end you need to decide what operation would like to do with this numbers (+,-,/,*). My problem is that I don't know how to take those inputted numbers from methods to main() so i could make operations on that.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int integer()
{
    int number1;
    int number2;
    cout << "First number: " << endl;
    cin >> number1;
    cout << "Second number: " << endl;
    cin >> number2;
}

double doubl()
{
    double number1;
    double number2;
    cout << "First number: " << endl;
    cin >> number1;
    cout << "Second number: " << endl;
    cin >> number2;
}

int main()
{

cout << "Type to choose:" << endl;
cout << "1. int" << endl;
cout << "2. double" << endl;

int choosed;
cin >> choosed;


switch(choosed) {
    case 1:
        integer();
        break;
    case 2:
        doubl();
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        break;
}

cout << "What operation would like to do on this numbers?" << endl;
cout << "1. +" << endl;
cout << "2. -" << endl;
cout << "3. *" << endl;
cout << "4. /" << endl;

int result;

switch(result){ //at this point i don't know how to invoke those numbers from      methods
    case 1:  
}

cin.get();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but unfortunately it's far harder than you think.  Basically, if you're going to work on two different types, the "work" will have to be completely sepereate as well.  They can't share "work" unless you have templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can return a `std::pair` from your functions

```
std::pair<double,double> doubl()
{
  ...
  return std::make_pair(number1,number2);
}
```

Then use it

```
std::pair<double,double> nums = doubl();
double res = nums.first <operation> nums.second;
```

When you feel comfortable with this I would recommend you to look into using templates to create your reading functions.

Comment: sounds interesting,i will check and let you know

Comment: could you explain the second frame? how to implement this to switch("operations switch")?;)

Comment: @Fastkowy: You will learn more if you research it yourself. So I will let that be an exercise for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it in C++. Basically, you have to store your answers in a variable in main() and you can use a flag to tell you whether it is a `int` or a `double` variable and operation.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class numbers
{
   private:
   T num1;
   T num2;

   public:
   numbers() : num1(0), num2(0) {}
   void setvalues(T n1, T n2) {num1 = n1; num2 = n2;}
   T add()      {return num1 + num2;}
   T subtract() {return num1 - num2;}
   T multiply() {return num1 * num2;}
   T divide()   {return (num2 != 0) ? num1 / num2 : 0;}
};

void integer(numbers<int>& numo)
{
    int number1;
    int number2;
    cout << "First number: " << endl;
    cin >> number1;
    cout << "Second number: " << endl;
    cin >> number2;
    numo.setvalues(number1, number2);
}

void doubl(numbers<double>& numo)
{
    double number1;
    double number2;
    cout << "First number: " << endl;
    cin >> number1;
    cout << "Second number: " << endl;
    cin >> number2;
    numo.setvalues(number1, number2);
}

int main()
{

cout << "Type to choose:" << endl;
cout << "1. int" << endl;
cout << "2. double" << endl;

int choosed;
cin >> choosed;

numbers<int> num_int;
numbers<double> num_dbl;
int typeOfVal = 0; // 1 for integer, 2 for double

switch(choosed) {
    case 1:
        integer(num_int);
        typeOfVal = 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        doubl(num_dbl);
        typeOfVal = 2;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        return 1;
}


int typeOfOp = 0;
cout << "What operation would like to do on this numbers?" << endl;
cout << "1. +" << endl;
cout << "2. -" << endl;
cout << "3. *" << endl;
cout << "4. /" << endl;
cin >> typeOfOp;

int resint; //result for int
double resdbl; // result for double

switch(typeOfOp){ 
    case 1: 
      if (typeOfVal == 1) resint = num_int.add(); else resdbl = num_dbl.add();
      break;
    case 2: 
      if (typeOfVal == 1) resint = num_int.subtract(); else resdbl = num_dbl.subtract();
      break;
    case 3: 
      if (typeOfVal == 1) resint = num_int.multiply(); else resdbl = num_dbl.multiply();
      break;
    case 4: 
      if (typeOfVal == 1) resint = num_int.divide(); else resdbl = num_dbl.divide();
    default:
      cout << "Error" << endl;
      return 1;
}

cout << "The answer:" << endl;
if (typeOfVal == 1) cout << resint << endl;
else cout << resdbl << endl;

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would have written the code like this: I think it is more standard than any other above code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
const string EXIT = "-1";
void add(float num1, float num2)
{
    cout<<"Result is: "<< num1 + num2 <<endl;
}
void subtract(float num1, float num2)
{
    cout<<"Result is: "<< num1 - num2 <<endl;
}
void multiply(float num1, float num2)
{
    cout<<"Result is: "<< num1 * num2 <<endl;
}
void divide(float numerator, float denominator)
{
    if (denominator != 0)
        cout<<"Result is: "<< numerator / denominator <<endl;
    else
        cout<<"You can not divide by denominator\n";
}
void modulus(float num1, float num2)
{
    cout<<"Result is: "<<  (int)num1 % (int)num2 <<endl;
}
int main(void)
{
    string mathematicalOperation;
    float num1, num2;
    char operatorSign;

    cout << "Please enter an arithmetic expression (-1 to Exit)\n";
    cin >> mathematicalOperation;
    //search for operator sign and perform calculation
    while(mathematicalOperation.compare(EXIT))
    {
        int getFirstDigitIndex = mathematicalOperation.find_first_of("0123456789");
        int operatorSignIndex = mathematicalOperation.find_first_of("+-*/%", getFirstDigitIndex);

        if (operatorSignIndex != -1)
        {   
            operatorSign = mathematicalOperation.at(operatorSignIndex);

            string firstNumber = mathematicalOperation.substr(0,operatorSignIndex);
            string secondNumber = mathematicalOperation.substr(operatorSignIndex + 1);
            //convert numbers from string to float
            num1 = (float)atof(firstNumber.c_str());
            num2 = (float)atof(secondNumber.c_str());
            switch(operatorSign)
            {
                case '+':
                    add(num1,num2);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    subtract(num1,num2);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    multiply(num1,num2);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    divide(num1,num2);
                    break;
                case '%':
                    modulus(num1,num2);
                    break;
            }
        }

        cout<<"Please Enter Another Expression or Enter -1 to Exit:\n";
        cin>>mathematicalOperation;
    }
    cout<<"SEE YOU LATER!\n";
    return 0;
}
```